# Are questions about German literature on-topic?

Tags: discussion, on-topic

With *German literature* I mean

- Literaturepochen/-strömungen (transl. please, "Does this piece pertain to Romantisicm?")
- German authors (e.g. their style of writing)
- Searching for texts (e.g. "I am looking for a text which best represents Schiller's use of...", "Is there a Sonnet about death?")

This list does not represent a definition of German literature. To me, *discussing the finer points of German language* simply implies the above.

Comment: I think this question is a little vague. Yes, German literature is on-topic as it's still German. However, the question must fit to what we define as on-topic. If there's a particular phrase, for instance, in that literature, it's absolutely fine to ask for interpretation or the like. If a question is about what we think of this literature, it's not OK.

Comment: @Em1 Questions about the meaning of single phrases are on-topic anyway (under certain circumstances). I'm reffering to questions about single phrases and the relation to their author or literary epoch.

Comment: @Em1 but the reasoning (as i read it) that you provide as to why 'what we think questions' are off topic is incorrect. These questions are not off-topic as defined by help center, but because they are primarily opinion based.

Answer (score 4):

As [suggested by Wrzlprmft](https://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/message/48242445#48242445) in the chat room, I am posting an answer to see if we can reach a consensus on this question.

I would consider the following types of literature-related questions as **off-topic**:

- Does work X belong to epoch Y (e.g. Romanticism)? Answers to such questions would normally be based on the date, content and writing style of the work rather than on purely linguistic aspects. By writing style, I here refer to linguistic aspects that go beyond phrase-level or sentence-level aspects.
- Do the works of author X belong to German literature? This means that the question [Are the works of Kafka considered German literature?](https://german.stackexchange.com/q/28550/22704) would be off-topic in spite of its 16 upvotes. This question is specifically about "sociopolitical distinction[s]" and the definition of "German literature". Making this question on-topic would require renaming the site to "German Language and Literature Stack Exchange".
- Where can I find the text of work X?
- Did author X really write poem Y?
- When did author X write/publish work Y?
- In German literature, is there a work similar to X in [English/French/Spanish/Chinese/...] literature. Example: [What's the “The Anatomy of Melancholy” of German literature?](https://german.stackexchange.com/q/48513/22704), which as put on hold on 23.12.2018.
- Is literary genre X a subset of literary genre Y? For example, [Is a Krimi a subset of a Roman?](https://german.stackexchange.com/q/48129/22704). Genre definitions are literary questions, not linguistic questions.
- Recommendations for works of literature. For example, [Simple but interesting German literature](https://german.stackexchange.com/q/620/22704). This question was preserved for historical reasons, stating that '"big list" questions are not generally allowed on German Language and Usage and will be closed per the [FAQ](https://german.stackexchange.com/faq#dontask).'

Of course, linguistic questions encountered in works of literature are **on-topic**. For example,

- What does the word X in work Y mean? For example, [What does the verb “halten” with a dative object mean?](https://german.stackexchange.com/q/44642/22704) It doesn't really matter whether you encountered a certain linguistic feature on the radio, on the Internet, in a newspaper or in a work of fiction.
- What linguistic resource can help me read/understand work X / the works of author Y / works from epoch Z? For example, [Welches Wörterbuch kann mir helfen, damit ich Goethes “Faust” verstehe?](https://german.stackexchange.com/q/40622/22704) (This type of question is OK from the point of view of distinguishing linguistic questions from purely literary ones. However, this type of question risks being read as a recommendation question, and the question [What to do with our book recommendation questions?](https://german.meta.stackexchange.com/q/518/22704) does not have an answer at the time of writing.)
- What is the difference in meaning between word X and word Y in work Z / epoch Z / ...? For example, [Bedeutung und Unterschied zwischen “Läuterung” und “Verklärung” im poetischen Realismus](https://german.stackexchange.com/q/35536/22704).

What I have tried to do here is define a **dividing line** between on "German" in a linguistic sense (on-topic) versus "German" in a non-linguistic sense (e.g. history of literature, sociopolitical questions) when questions somehow involve literature. Questions about lexical and grammatical issues found in works of literature are on-topic.

---

This is a first attempt to define a borderline between linguistic questions and (non-linguistic) literary questions. Please comment if the distinction is not sufficiently clear. And feel free to add another answer that defines a different borderline. Consensus on questions like this can only be reached through a community effort.

Comment: I put that question on the featured list in the hope that more people will read it and cast their votes.

Comment: @Takkat Excellent idea! Thanks.

Comment: Can you find a criterion for on- or off-topicness that may be easily translated to future cases? (I acknowledge that this may be difficult.)

Comment: @Wrzlprmft I added a paragraph about a "dividing line" just about the horizontal ruler. Is this clear enough? If not, we may need to refine this further in the chat.